# PDO statements foreach inside a loop

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, foreach, sql-insert

Am using prepare statement to insert an array of statements to my database. But am facing problem to insert it properly. my code looks like this way 
i have $requests array

```
(
    [0] => 456908497765326_100004069844270
    [1] => 456908497765326_100000058716604
)

$stmt = $this->core->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO fb_requests(user_id,fb_user_id,request_id,game_selected,accept_status) VALUES(:user_id,:fb_user_id,:request_id,:game_selected,:outstanding)");
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
    echo "counter value".$i; echo"</br>";
    foreach($requests as $requestid) {
        echo "request value".$requestid; echo"</br>";
        $stmt->execute(array('user_id'=>$user_id,':fb_user_id' => $uid, ':request_id' => $requestid,':game_selected' => $i, ':outstanding' => $outstanding));
    }
}
```

The insertion is working for inner foreach loop only. I can see two rows inserted in to my database. But the outer for loop is not working. I expect 4 rows insertion in to my database. Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: What's your db schema like?

Comment: Perhaps you have a unique constraint somewhere that prevents multiple insertions? If you enable exception error mode the script would fail if that's the case.

Comment: @jack, thank you so much for you quick reply. Your guess is right. I had a unique constrain there.. One again. Thank you so much for your help and support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a unique index somewhere.

```
$stmt = $this->core->dbh->prepare("
    INSERT INTO fb_requests (user_id, fb_user_id, request_id, game_selected, accept_status)
    VALUES (:user_id, :fb_user_id, :request_id, :game_selected, :outstanding)
");

for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    echo "counter value $i<br>";
    foreach($requests as $requestid) {
        echo "request value $requestid<br>";
        try {
            $stmt->execute(array(
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'fb_user_id' => $uid,
                'request_id' => $requestid,
                'game_selected' => $i,
                'outstanding' => $outstanding
            ));
        } catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }

        var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());
    }
}
```

You should attempt to catch any exceptions to see what is going on. I edited your code to add some formatting so I could read it. Give that a shot to see what, if any, issues are goi

Comment: This only works if you do `$this->core->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERROMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` first.

Comment: Your guess is correct i had a unique constrain in one of my fields. Thanks for you quick response.. Thanks a lot